# Forecasting product return rates based on past returns

Tags: python, forecasting, finance, weibull

I have a waterfall dataset which shows the returns of laptops over different weeks due to defects. For sales of each month it shows returns over different months
[image: returns data]

I transformed the data to a weekly level: For example the returns column will be the returns of the first month for each sale month.(it will be the sum of the first diagonal
[image]

I fit the pdf into a 2 parameter weibull distribution which models failure rates. (to approximate a bathtub curve)

I then used the fit curve to estimate reliability rates form the predicted cdf. Using that the unreliability rate is predicted.

However the Weibull distribution does not accurately model a bathtub curve which is frequent with failure rates and hence the accuracy is quite low.

Is there a better approach to this problem of predicted return rates?

Comment: Probably you don't need to worry about the right side of the bathtub curve on such a short scale; Weibull should be fine. If you have data on when a returned laptop was sold, it is possible to use survival modeling instead.